# "htop" style gui with python, how?

Tags: python, user-interface, text

I am intersted in building some text based GUIs, things that look like the terminal, but has functions like selecting rows and performing actions.

You know, things like htop and atop, ex:

[image: atop]

[image: htop]

Any resource on that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need [Uwrid](http://excess.org/urwid/) - a console user interface library for Python.

Documentation available on the website.

There is also [Curses](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html), which is in the Python standard library.

Answer (score 1):

don't miss http://pythondialog.sourceforge.net/ also

Comment: does not support menu,list and other components used in htop

Answer (score 1):

Also, the library [panwid](https://github.com/tonycpsu/panwid) offers a data table widget for Urwid, which does a lot of the heavy-lifting for an htop-like interface.