# python termios mode like in 'htop, atop' utulities

Tags: python, terminal

How to work with terminal window in mode when it is possible to operate with each cell by it coords? I dont know how this mode named, thats why I cant google it. Also, I know about [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224933/htop-style-gui-with-python-how), but now it is interesting for me how to work with it low level.

**UPD:**
Ok, I read all the termios man page and some other docs, and the only thing I could say now - I still dont know how to make rotating bar somewhere in the terminal, ie by frames: - \ | / - .:(

**UPD2**
Oh, I suddenly found it [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122385/dynamic-terminal-printing-with-python?rq=1):

```
import sys
import time

f='-\\|/'

for i in range(10):
    sys.stdout.write("\r{0}".format(f[i%4]))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

So, the last question in this topic - what about *any coordinates only with termios*?

**Subquestion[SOLVED]:**

When I use `curses` ie the second code listing from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2122972/1531116) - it makes my semi-transparent terminal window no-transparent, when `top` does not do this. How to keep it transparent?

solution: insert `curses.use_default_colors()` in the first string of `def pbar(window):`.

Comment: you may want to mention operating system...since it will change significantly depending on which OS you are using (NO portability...)

Comment: @JoranBeasley of course it is linux (ubuntu 12.04), does windows users know the word 'terminal'?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a lower level library than [`curses`](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html), you can use [`termios`](http://docs.python.org/library/termios.html) (although I would suspect htop's UI is written mainly with curses)

The Python docs page on `termios` are minimal as the module pretty much just exposes the underlying UNIX'y termios library, so non-Python-specific docs are the main source of information, [like this guide on termios](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming/termios), or [the termios.h header](http://linux.die.net/man/3/termios) (or run `man termios` in a shell)

Of course the challenge is translating the code into Python, but usually the translation is reasonably straight forward (the function calls are usually very similar, and the bit-swizzling/bit-masking is often identical)

Answer (score 1):

curses ( http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html ) or Console ( http://effbot.org/zone/console-handbook.htm ) modules are what you want

the source of Console.py is available here http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~gfrancis/illimath/windows/aszgard_mini/pylibs/readline/Console.py Im sure you could look at that...  although Im sure its probably a big pain and thats why people always use curses...

On windows you may want to browse msdn
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx
and call it using ctypes.cdll.whatever

Comment: no, dude, did you read this - "I know about this approach, but now it is interesting for me how to work with it low level"? Im asking about something like termios.tcgetattr()!

Comment: I think you will need to use ctypes for that... not sure ... its a big pain I think...the source of Console.py is available here http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~gfrancis/illimath/windows/aszgard_mini/pylibs/readline/Console.py Im sure you could look at that...

Comment: wow, it is too hardcore:))) _still looking for simple example_